# Cron has troubles running Rscript through a bash script

Tags: r, bash, cron, rscript

Hi I have a simple cron task  `0 0 * * 1 /usr/bin/env bash /home/(me)/Downloads/news-scrape/weekly.sh`. In the "weekly.sh" script I have

```
#! /bin/bash

Rscript script.r

##remaining code, simple bash if else statement
```

In the "script.r" Rscript, I have a rather complex scraping algorithm using Rselenium and some other packages. Now weekly.sh runs as intended in the terminal but when I call that cron task I get this error message

```
Fatal error: cannot open file '/home/erdman.35/Downloads/tdai-news-scrape-master/srcript.r': No such file or directory
find: ‘report.csv’: No such file or directory
No new news articles found
Can't stat report.csv: No such file or directory
report.csv: unable to attach file.
```

Now report.csv is an output of the rscript, so the main issue is the lack of the Rscript executing properly, I have "chmod +x"'d it so it's executable and still it doesn't run. Any idea what my issue may be?

Comment: (1) `script.r` vs `srcript.r`? (2) How certain are you that the working directory (`pwd` in bash, `getwd()` in R) is what you assume it will be? (3) It is possible that the packages you think are available (e.g., `RSelenium`) are not available based on the env-var filters that `/usr/bin/env` will do. I suggest you add some debugging in your R script that clearly logs what its `.libPaths()` is, when run locally compared with running within cron.

Comment: You can add `pwd` above your call to `Rscript` to see where the script is running.

Comment: Try changing the shell script to `/usr/bin/Rscript /full/path/to/script.r`

Comment: All these "no such file or directory" messages should be pretty good indication.  Files missing, typos, permissions, ...  Cron does not start your script under the same environment as the one you use on the command line.  Research, these questions abound as to how to fix that.